# Laravel Delete Items within Edit View

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5 and I need to call a destroy Method inside my edit view.
All examples I found cover this separated with an index view and two buttons (one for editing and one for deleting).
Can somebody give me a hint to call a destroy Method inside an edit view?

Comment: you copy the button code and put it inside your edit view , done!

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code anywhere, not just in index view. Just create a link and use `get` route or use `destroy` route with form button to send a request:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'Delete', 'route' => ['someroute.destroy', $id]]) !!}
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the show view of the item

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.destroy', $post->id) }}" method="POST">
     {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete Post</button>
</form>
```